# Waring's problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The first comment on [OEIS A002379](http://oeis.org/A002379) states:

> It is an important unsolved problem related to Waring's problem to show that a(n) = floor((3^n-1)/(2^n-1)) holds for all n >= 1. This has been checked for 10000 terms and is true for all sufficiently large n, by a theorem of Mahler. [Lichiardopol]

**Edit -- a new equality**
$$
\frac{2^n( 3^n \mod 2^n)}{4^n-2^n} -\frac{3^n \mod 2^n}{4^n-2^n} -\frac{2^n( (-2+3^n) \mod (-1+2^n))}{4^n-2^n}
-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n +\frac{3^n}{2^{n-1}} -\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} +\frac{2^{2 n}}{4^n-2^n} -\frac{2^{n+1}}{4^n-2^n} = 1
$$

The items with $4^n-2^n$ in the denominators are distances and the items with $2$ or $2^{n-1}$ are locations on the number line.

An alternate form is:
$$
\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3^n}{2^n-1}-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: 'holds' means the same thing as 'is true'

Comment: concerning your argument in the edit: no, that doesn't suffice alone. I can't explain it in length at the moment, but you might look at the picture at page 20 in http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf where I discussed exactly this problem in the context of the "primitive" collatz-cycle - it should give an intuition, why this does not suffice . (Perhaps I can come back to this later today)

Comment: What do you mean, "does it work"? Do you mean, "does this bit of high school algebra solve an important, well-known open problem that the experts have struggled with for decades"?

Comment: Additionally, there was some much similar discussion at MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108489

Comment: Just a sidenote: the final anser can be simplified to $$ {\log(6^3)\over \log(6^2)} = {3 \cdot \log(6) \over 2 \cdot \log(6)} = \frac 32 $$ to make things clearer.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, thanks. The image is from _WolframAlpha_, so I will put the simplication into my LaTeX version.

Comment: From your profile: "When I look at the patterns, I can hear the wheels turning. When I look at the math, I find out the hamsters have died." I will surely remember this for a long time.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I have a proof. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/730053/28555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$ {3^n-1\over2^n-1} = 3^n{1 \over 2^n-1} -{1 \over 2^n-1} \\
= {3^n \over 2^n} (1+ \frac 1{2^n}+\frac 1{4^n}) -\frac 1{2^n } (1+ \frac 1{2^n}+\frac 1{4^n}) \\ =  {3^n \over 2^n} + \left(\frac {3^n}{4^n}-\frac {2^n}{4^n} +\frac {3^n}{8^n}-\frac {2^n}{8^n}+... \right)   $$
and it is not obvious, that the parenthese is smaller than the difference of $\frac {3^n}{2^n}$ to the next integer above. In the contrary, this is very near the detail in the Waring problem (and only slightly weaker than the (unproven) conjecture) that the parenthese in
$$ {3^n \over 2^n} + \left(\frac {3^n}{4^n} - 0 + 0 ...  \right)   $$ is smaller than that difference.

---

The following picture is meant to make the problem more visible, that the question is that of the distance of $(3/2)^r$ to the next integer. I've drawn the x-axis of the real numbers, two marks at consecutive integer numbers floor and ceil $(3/2)^N$ and three examples of possible positions of the $(3/2)^N$ ***in*** that interval, such that the Collatz/Waring-intervals around $(3/2)^N$ interfer in three different ways with that consecutive integers. Positions 1 and 3 contradict the expectations from the Waring-related and the COllatz-related intervals, and for positions $k$ we see, that the intervals are inside the bounds given by the consecutive integers.
I've also added a further definition of bounds for an interval around $(3/2)^N$, which is always smaller than the unit-interval but includes the Collatz/Waring-intervals, which I've not seen before/elsewhere. It ensures, that *at most* $1$ integer is in that interval.

[image]

The question is: how do we know, that $(3/2)^N$ is at an appropriate position in the unit-interval of the consecutive integers?

Comment: I appologize for unaccepting your answer, but I feel there is more insight to be gained when we get more views.

Comment: @Fred: No problem; but I think you are -for mysterious reasons:-) - missing the point of the "Waring-problem": whatever small that difference might be, letting $r\to \infty$, the significant question is, whether there is an integer (aktually the ceil-function) in that interval. It might be helpful to look at $3^n \cdot c+1$ instead of $3^n \cdot c - 1$ to make oneself more familiar with that problem... Perhaps I can also add a more visual explanation in my post later today.

Comment: @Fred, no one has posted anything new here for over a week, but you expect something to come of getting more views?

Comment: @Fred: here is a note on which I was working in August (but which is not yet ready, and possibly will not further due to weak health of mine). Hopefully it is selfexplanatory enough, otherwise ask: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/1cycleErg.pdf

Comment: The difference, as I see it, is that I am using a meta-pattern. I use all of the rank 2 (say) suborbits to show they all have the identical floor.  Since the Waring problem is only referencing the first number of each rank, it is a minute part of the problem. So, by showing that all ranks of suborbits have identical floors withing their ranks, we show that the single reference by Waring has the same characteristis.

Comment: I use the row calculations of Nicomachus's Triangle to calculate all suborbits of a particular rank.\cr The insertion of $c$ into Nicomachus's Triangle row calculations is the key to a tractable proof.

Comment: @Fred: I do not have an idea what you mean with "suborbits" (or even only "orbits") here. Would you mind to formulate that (at best in some new answer while "answering your own question" in MSE-lingo). Perhaps I can then say more about this...

Comment: Using my meta-pattern we can show the fractional part to be $<\frac{1}{2}$ (skipping the first entry.) This fraction tends toward $0$ as the rank increases.

Comment: @Fred - well, if we extend the domain for the Collatz to the negative integers we get some cycles because(?) there are three contradictions for low numbers N with an integer in the interval $ { 3^N+1 \over 2^N+1 } \ldots {3^N \over 2^N} $ ...

Comment: upps- I had to correct wrong signs in the formulas in the picture - sorry...

Comment: I do not use $\frac{3^N+1}{2^N+1}$ in any of my work because it places things outside the boundaries of the finite sub orbits (sequences). So, I guess I'm working on a sub-set of both problems.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n$ is defined as the floor of $3^n/2^n$. The unsolved problem is whether that is always equal to the floor of ${3^n-1\over2^n-1}$.

EDIT: where "always" seems to mean "for all $n\ge2$".

Answer (score 1):

*This is another answer, motivated by [your additional query at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151318/), where it likely gets/stays closed. Because I understand now your question there in a better way this answer my be useful also for the question here.*

First (the first formula in MO) does nothing else than to express the difference between $ {3^n\over2^n} $ and $ {3^n-1\over2^n-1} $ .Nothing in this to be proved.
Second you ask, whether *"a proof of that formula would also prove the formula"* $$ \left\lfloor {3^n\over2^n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor {3^n-1\over2^n-1} \right\rfloor$$
which indeed is the critical conjecture (and only slightly different from that difficult and unproven conjecture from the Waring problem).

Well, the first formula contains nothing to prove - it is just a statement of the difference, but where an explicite expansion and cancellation can help to express it in a very intuitive way - and only after that it remains to show/prove , that also the expression by the second formula is actually not only empirically but analytically true. So here goes my second thought on it.

First consider the representation of the numbers in the digit-system of $2^n$. Let's write 
$$ 3^n  = m 2^n + r \qquad \qquad r \in (0..2^n-1) \tag 1 $$
Then in the digit system base $b=2^n$ we have
$$ 3^n = \mathtt{"m r.000"_{|_b}}  \tag 2 $$    and
$$ {3^n \over 2^n} = \mathtt{"m. r000"_{|_b}} \tag 3 $$
Now $ {3^n \over 2^n-1} ={3^n/2^n \over 1-1/2^n}  $  is a geometric series with quotient $2^n$ and occurs as a repunit:
$$ {3^n/2^n \over 1-1/2^n} = \mathtt{" m. r" + "0.mr" +"0.0mr"+ ... _{|_b}} \tag 4$$
which can then be written as
$$ {3^n \over 2^n-1} = \qquad \begin{array} {rcl}
       & &  \mathtt {\; ^"m.m m m m m m \ldots \; ^"} \\
        &+& \mathtt {\; ^"0.r r r r r r \ldots\; ^"}  _{|_b}
 \end{array} \tag 5$$ and if we append the missing $ { -1\over 2^n-1}$ we get
$$ {3^n -1 \over 2^n-1} =  \qquad \begin{array} {rcl}
& & \mathtt{ \; ^"   m.m m m m m m \ldots  \; ^" } \\
&+& \mathtt{ \; ^"   0.r r r r r r \ldots \; ^" }  \\
&-& \mathtt{ \; ^"   0.1 1 1 1 1 1 \ldots \; ^" }  \\
\end{array} _{|_b}  \tag 6 $$ 
In (3) we see, that $m$ is the floor-value for $3^n/2^n$ and what your second question asks, whether (3) and (6) result in the same floor-value.

With this representation we see easily, that this can only happen, if the expression of the summands after the decimal points do not give a carry on each single "digit", that means, that, the floor-equality is only true if
$$ m + r - 1 \lt b-1 \tag 7$$
or with the reference to a general/indeterminate $n$
$$ m_n + r_n - 1 \lt 2^n-1 \tag 8$$

*(This can be reworked to fit into the notations of the Waring-problem.)*

---

A correct handling of your problem is thus:

Your first question, whether "a proof of the first equation in MO is also a proof of the equality of the floors" is actually a thinking in circles: in this first equation there is ***nothing to prove***, it is just the formulation of the difference between the two expressions  $ {3^n\over2^n} $ and $ {3^n-1\over2^n-1} $ .

It can be reformulated such that it becomes better visible, ***what*** in fact must be proved: and that is that condition (7) or (8) holds not only empirically for a lot of values $n$ but for analytical reasons for all $n$ (perhaps above a certain lower bound).

Comment: The denominator in the first statement is the LCM of $2^n(2^n-1)$ which is a Mersenne number $\times$ power of two. In base 2 for (say) $2^3(2^3-1)$ it is $111000_2$. Maybe we can show that the carries cannot go all the way up. For Collatz we do not need identical 'floors', we need only to show that both values are always fractions.

Comment: @Fred: To your last sentence in your comment: only to make sure there is no misunderstanding: since all digits "m.mmmm..." are equal (and the same with "0.rrrr...." and "0.111111...") and because that strings are of infinite length, we have either no carry or a carry everywhere which propagates then to the first digit which becomes then "m+1" and we have then a change in the floor-function. So for "m+r-1" at least equalling $b-1$ we had such a carry, and when $ \mathtt{"m+r} \lt b $ we have none. Now what does the empirical test show...

Comment: @fred :To the first sentence in your comment: it might be of interest that there exists an article which discusses the problem from the number of occuring zeros in the bitstring of the binomial expansion. It is a long time I've seen this but might be interesting in your indicated point-of-view.

Comment: I will be taking the rest of the month to attend to real life issues--holidays, apartment remodeling, and chronic internet outages. Back in January.

Comment: Here I link http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42095/question-about-reduce-of-an-inequality to a post where I determine that (3^n-1)/(2^n-1) is always a fraction.  No integers for $n>1$.

Comment: Hi @Fred - no problem with your last one. The difficulty occurs when $ { 3^n \cdot k-1\over 2^n \cdot k-1 }$ with some integer $k \ge 1$. *(Also it might be more opportune to write $ { 3^n -j\over 2^n -j }$ instead, but not neccessarily)*

Comment: I am posting an update with (2n-1) instead of the k to make sure it is odd.

Comment: FYI, the -1 is a one, not an ell.