# What do these contour maps tell me about my Collatz expression?

Tags: limits, collatz-conjecture, experimental-mathematics

I tested this limit on *WolframAlpha*,
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {2\ 3^r (2 t - 1) - 6} {3\ 2^r (2 t - 1) - 
      6}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{r-1},$$

which displayed two contour maps:

[image] [image].

Can someone describe the what we are seeing? Anything notable?

**Edit** Question has been answered, but I've added motivaton. In *Mathematica*, when we take the limit to a specific triangle $t$, we get a generating function for that triangle that produces all numbers that need to be proved to always be fractions, in order to prove there are no loop-backs in Collatz. Say we set $t\rightarrow2$, we get $\frac{2 \left(3^r-1\right)}{3\ 2^r-2}$, then we get $\{\frac{8}{5},\frac{26}{11},\frac{80}{23},\frac{242}{47},\frac{728}{95},\frac{2186}{191},\frac{6560}{383},\frac{1514}{59},\frac{59048}{1535}\}$ for the first few $r$'s. If we can prove this for all triangles, we can show that no looping occurs in Collatz.

Comment: Once you have ${ 2\over3 }{ 3^r-1\over2^r-2 } $  this is always non-integer because in the denominator you've the primefactor $3$ but not in the numerator...

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108489/is-an-integer-in-the-interval-left-small-3n1-over-2n1-lt-3n-over-2

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, Is this sequence $$\left\{2,\frac{8}{5},\frac{14}{9},\frac{20}{13},\frac{26}{17},\frac{32}{21},    \frac{38}{25},\frac{44}{29},\frac{50}{33},\frac{56}{37}\right\}$$ the 1-cycle?

Comment: No , a 1-cycle would be the set of the following numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ where $a_{k+1}=(3 a_k+1)/2$ and $a_1 = (3a_n+1)/2^A$ with some positive integer A. The only such set in the positive odd numbers is $(a_k)=(1)$ (proven by R. Steiner 1977) but over the negative integers we have $(a_k)=(-1)$ and $(a_1,a_2)=(-5,-7)$. (The set beginning with $-17$ forms a 2-cycle with elements $(-17,-25,-37,-55,  -41,-61,-91)$)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, thanks. The sequence above shows all the potential 1-cycles per my definition. I have two inequalities that show that the first item is the only cycle. I can show this for all potential cycles. _My definition of cycles is different from the usual, but I can show it covers all numbers $\in\textbf{Z}$._

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I posted the preliminary proofs of the 1-Cycle: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055394/28555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit is rather simple, being of the form $lim_{t\to \infty}(at+b)/(ct+d)=a/c$. The fact that $r$ and $t$ be integer and $t$ a multiple of $r$ has no impact, there is still an accumulation point at $\infty$.

The plot is of little use, but the 3D view clearly shows the exponential behavior as a function of $r$, just perturbed by the zeroes of the denominator. These appear as an exponential curve on the 2D diagram but are irrelevant for the limit computation.